# Which is the proper Gradle plugin to support 'provided' method?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, lombok

I'm currently trying to include Project Lombok helper into my Gradle project, but while following [their instructions for Gradle](http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/index.html) within my build.gradle, I'm getting the following error:

Error:(11, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'provided()'!

Possible causes could be:

- you are using Gradle version where the method is absent
- you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
- or there is a mistake in a build script

My current build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.4"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: FWIW I've just added my installed lombok.jar as a compile dependency. It's not exactly the same, but it works and I'm ignorant enough to enjoy it. ;)

Comment: Hello @maaartinus thanks a lot for the comment also. This seems to sort out this problem - builds properly the script, but then fails to compile while not able to resolve Project Lombok's annotation symbols.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As of release 2.12, `provided` scope is called [`compileOnly`](https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes#support-for-declaring-compile-time-only-dependencies-with-java-plugin)

---

Old answer:

Provided scope is available in 'war' plugin (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html , providedCompile ) If You don't want to use the 'war' plugin, there is also an opened JIRA issue regarding 'provided' scope http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784 , suggested workaround is to create Your own cofiguration:

```
configurations {
   provided
}
```

and set it to be used with your compilation classpath:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @endriu_l Thanks for the answer, I've tried adding: "apply plugin: 'war'" (without double quotes OFC) just below the other plugin I had, but still the same problem. Should I add something else?

Comment: @kapitanpattimura , in 'war' plugin, this scope is called 'providedCompile', so just change 'provided' to 'providedCompile' and everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Check your app level gradle file. If any line looks like this:

```
compile dependency.gson provided dependency.javaxAnnotation
```

Edit it like this:

```
compile dependency.gson 
provided dependency.javaxAnnotation
```

It should work.